# Error writting file to S3 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, databricks

I trying to write the output using databricks notebook from this code using df write to a S3 bucket, but getting this error:

**Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 20.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 20.0 (TID 50, 10.239.78.116, executor 0): java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: tfstest/0/outputFile/_started_7476690454845668203: regular upload on tfstest/0/outputFile/_started_7476690454845668203: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied; request: PUT https://tfs-databricks-sys-test.s3.amazonaws.com tfstest/0/outputFile/_started_7476690454845668203 {}**

```
val outputFile = "s3a://tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Incte_19&20.csv" //  OUTPUT path 

val df3 = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("s3a://tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/rawdata.csv")            

val writer = df3.coalesce(1).write.csv("outputFile")

filtinp.foreach(x => {
  val (com1, avg1) = com1Average(filtermp, x)
  val (com2, avg2) = com2Average(filtermp, x)
  })

def getFileSystem(path: String): FileSystem = {
val hconf = new Configuration() // initialize new hadoop configuration
new Path(path).getFileSystem(hconf) // get new filesystem to handle data
```

It seems to be a permissions issue, but I'm able to write to this S3 bucket doing a Union for example, with two dataframes in same location, so I don't get what's really happening here. Also, note the path show in the error **https://tfs-databricks-sys-test.s3.amazonaws.com** is not the path I'm trying to use.

Comment: also I don't know where this path comes from tfstest/0/outputFile/_started_7476690.....

Comment: Try change val writer = df3.coalesce(1).write.csv("outputFile") to val writer = df3.coalesce(1).write.csv(outputFile). (remove quotes from variable name)

Comment: thnks, I got now java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: this could be related to other code that you have mentioned, can you debug it line by line

Comment: ok. don't know why if I use PrintWriter instead dataframe write always complains about not file found, using S3 and always get the path with one  "s3a:/ " instead  "s3a://" trying to write the ouput to a new file there(in S3 bucket), any possible explanation?